# Pasar parámetro de input a función en JS

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un imput de tipo texto en una pagina y quiero pasarlo como parametro a una funcion para que haga una tarea. Como podria hacerlo?

```js
//Milisegundos
function milisegundos(milisegundos) {
    var dms = new Date(milisegundos);
    alert("Fecha en milisegundos: "+dms);
}
```

```html
 <input type="text"><br>
 <input type="button" onclick="miFuncion()" value="Calcular los milisegundos">
```

Comment: No está claro lo que pides... Cuando haces click en el campo de texto llamas a la funcion `miFuncion()`. Si quieres pasar el propio campo de texto usa `this` como parametro ... es eso lo que quieres?

Comment: actualize la pregunta ya que miFuncion no era, sino milisegundos(). El tema es que quiero pasarle un parametro a la llamada de la funcion para quew dentro de la funcion pueda tratar con ese dato

Comment: entonces el campo de texto contiene el valor que ha de pasarse en la funcion?

Comment: `Date()` no te regresa milisegundos, si no un objeto de tipo fecha que contiene más información que los puros milisegundos de la fecha

Comment: Gracias por la recomendacion Yikarus, pero trato de pasarle los milisegundos para yo pasarlo a fecha y mostrarlo en pantalla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tienes más que darle un `id` al control para poder referenciarlo y obtener su valor:

```js
//Milisegundos
function milisegundos(milisegundos) {
    var dms = new Date(milisegundos);
    alert("Fecha en milisegundos: " + dms);
}
function miFuncion(){
  var control = document.getElementById('cant_milisegundos');
  var numero = parseInt(control.value);
  if (isNaN(numero)){
    alert('No es una cantidad válida');
    return;
  }
  
  milisegundos(numero);
}
```

```html
<input id="cant_milisegundos" type="text"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="miFuncion()" value="Calcular los milisegundos">
```

Comment: aaa que bueno, esta funcion recoge un valor comprueba que es numero y desde la misma funcion llama a otra. Buenisimo ejemplo, gracias por la ayuda amigo

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero, la funcion solo deberia llamarla el boton y no el input del texto tambien.
Te recomendaria acceder al elemento por la ID.

De esta manera, cuando clickes al boton, accedera al valor del input para guardarlo en la variable milisegundos. Despues lo tratara a date y te hara el alert.

```js
//Milisegundos
function miFuncion() {
    var milisegundos = document.getElementById("milisegundos").value;
    var dms = new Date(milisegundos);
    alert("Fecha en milisegundos: "+dms);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="milisegundos"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="miFuncion()" value="Calcular los milisegundos">
```